# How to refer to an image from a different assembly in a Windows Store app?

Tags: image, windows-runtime, embedded-resource

I have a Windows Store app where it's easy to reference an image stored as a content:

var image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/MyImage.png"));

But what if an image is stored in a different assembly as embedded resource? How can it be referenced? I tried different Uri notations, but none of them worked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

This should work if your asset is part of MyLibrary.dll in the Images folder:

```
var image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///MyLibrary/Images/MyImage.png"));
```

Comment: Hi Filip,
My question is about referencing an image that is stored as an embedded resource, not as a content. ms-appx notation does not seem to work for embedded resources.

Comment: There is no uri scheme to handle this for you. If you embed a resource you will need to extract it yourself.

Comment: Sure, but my question is how to extract an image embedded in another DLL. It's easy when I deal with a text resource. But in case of image I can only get a Stream object of the embedded resource, and BitmapImage requires IRandomAccessStream that is not assignable from Stream. I've seen examples where people copy a Stream object into InMemoryRandomAccessStream in order to pass it to a BitmapImage, but this seems to be an overkill (doing copy between streams). So I wonder if there is a more straighforward way.

Comment: I doubt that, since embedded resources are not supported as a common approach.

Comment: Thanks Filip. I've searched for way too long before finding your answer and realizing I needed to include the assembly name in the path -_-